# Google voice having trouble recognising some of what I say

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, voice-recognition

I'm English with a thick southern accent, and while Google voice does quite well about a 3rd of the time, it struggles with words such as slack (thinks I'm saying slap, flac, etc), medium (thinks I'm saying museum), slap (thinks I'm saying map), etc. I have repeated these words over and over, hundreds of times and it's not getting any better. I've tried speaking slower, louder, really enunciating my words, but nothing is helping.

I wanted to use Google voice as a way to quickly record my thoughts during the first stage of writing articles but it looks like that's not happening any time soon as I've tried saying whole sentences and short paragraphs over and over, but again, it struggles with that. It gets it right maybe 1 or 2 times out of 10.

Is there a knack to this? Is there a way to spell out words it struggles to understand so that it "remembers" these words for future use?

I'm using Marshmallow if that makes any difference, and the language is set to UK English.

Any tips?